# Way to pipe or stream Array in Numpy/Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, adafruit

This is my specific use case to better explain the problem, but I'm looking for a generalized solution.

I am using a Raspberry Pi with the adafruit LED display that displays an RGB matrix (this code is in Python 2). I have a python script that generates RGB data every 1/n seconds.

Is there a package or library that allows me to continuously generate RGB data in the form of an np.ndarray in one process and have it be polled by the the matrix script so that it does near-real time interprocess communication of numpy arrays.

Comment: Why "gives the appearance"? Why are you concerned about what it *looks* like your code is doing? Are you trying to *pretend* your code is streaming data between processes?

Comment: Sorry that was extremely poor wording. My use case is visual, but that's not related to my problem. I want to have some sort of synchronized interprocess communication on the same machine with numpy/scipy arrays. Feel free to ignore everything regarding Raspberry Pi if it makes it more confusing, I just thought someone else with Pi might have done something similar before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy and fast solution is to use the `numpy.memmap` [library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html). It just creates a memory-map to an array stored in a binary file on disk. In that way you can share numpy arrays between processes very easily and incredibly fast.

For example, the main process that generates the RGB data can be:

```py
import numpy as np
myshape = (100,100,3) # my RGB array
shared_array = np.memmap("/tmp/testarray", mode='w+', shape=myshape)

while True:
    data = some_function_to_get_rgb_data() # returns a numpy array of myshape
    shared_array[:] = data[:]
```

And the other process that reads that array can be:

```py
import numpy as np
read_shape = (100,100,3)
shared_array = np.memmap("/tmp/testarray", mode='r', shape=read_shape)

while True:
    # shared_array will behave as a numpy ndarray
    do_something_with_array(shared_array)
```

Only take into account that the shape must match (also the `dtype` of the array can be passed to the `memmap` function) and the process that creates the file must run first. In practice any change made to the `shared_array` in the main process will be reflected in the other process very fast.

Tests I have done sharing a (480,360,21) array with 4 processes simultaneously it takes less than 1 millisec to read and write from that array.

Comment: Do you need to have some synchronization mechanism?  How can you ensure that the consumer does not read in the middle of an update?

Comment: Good point, to be honest, I don't know how internally numpy is handling that. My guess is that they handle that locking for the user under the hood.